# removing an image from PPT Apache POI

Tags: java, image-processing, powerpoint, apache-poi

I've run into a situation:

```
 XSLFSlide xslfSlide = ppt.createSlide();

            for (XSLFShape shape : xslfSlide) {
                if (shape instanceof XSLFTextShape) {
                    //some code here
                } else if(shape instanceof XSLFPictureShape) {
                    //some code here
                }
            }
```

if I have a shape type XSLFPictureShape(simply saying - picture) it throws me an Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported shape: org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFPictureShape
```

Is there any way to remove an image from a slide?

Comment: What throws that exception? What were you trying to call when you got it? Maybe the full stacktrace might help?

Comment: if I try to perform `xslfSlide.removeShape(shape)`. As I described in question, it has type XSLFPictureShape

Answer (score 3):

After amanteaux raised a bug report, I've fixed this in [r1717018](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1717018)

After reading the comments, I've also added the missing table remove code in [r1717087](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1717087)

As for an answer, it's generally better to raise a bug at the projects issue tracking system than hoping that someone of a projects checks the posts at SO.
(I've stopped to track/answer SO posts, as I mostly got votes for no-brainers and not for stuff I worked several days/weeks ...)